# How to receive data in nvd3.js from a node.js server?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, d3.js

This may be a very straight forward question, but I am new to d3.js. node.js and even JavaScript in general.

I want to take data from a table in my MySQL database and plot it as a dynamic line graph (because the table keeps receiving stream data) using a graph from nvd3.js.

So far I have used node.js to create a server and get the lines from my table, convert them to JSON and print them. This is what I have:

```
var mysql= require('mysql');
var http = require('http');
var d3 = require("d3");
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : '****',
  user     : '****',
  password : '****',
 database: '****'
});


connection.connect() ;


http.createServer(function (request, response)
{

        connection.query('SELECT * FROM table', function(err, result)
        {

                response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
                response.end(JSON.stringify(result));

                response.end();
        });

}).listen(8084);
```

The issue now, is that because I want to plot a graph with nvd3.js using this data, I need to create an html file in which I can declare the libraries regarding nvd3, and plot the graph there. So something like this:

```
<html>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.min.js'>  </script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.1.15-beta/nv.d3.min.js'></script>
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.1.15-beta/nv.d3.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<div id='chart' style='height:500px'>
  <svg></svg>
  <script>
  nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.lineWithFocusChart();
    ....
```

My question is, how can I use the variable `result` from  my node.js server that holds the data I want in my html file? Should I be getting the data directly from port 8084? Do I even need to use html?

Thank you very much.

PS: Please DO NOT include solutions that include the use of PHP, as that is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an AJAX request. You could use jQuery to help you with that:

```
var url = "localhost:8084" // Change this accordingly

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    // Create your chart here, for now just log it:
    console.log(data);
}).fail(function() {
    // Something went wrong:
    console.log("Error");
});
```

### Demo

The following pie chart uses a JSON document from Stackoverflow's API. It shows the amount of questions that have no answers vs the amount of questions that have at least one answer (https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/info?site=stackoverflow)

```js
var chartElement = d3.select("#chart svg");
var chart;

nv.addGraph(function() {
  chart = nv.models.pieChart()
    .x(function(d) {
      return d.label
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return d.value
    })
    .showLabels(true)
    .noData("Waiting for server...");

  chartElement
    .datum([])
    .call(chart);

  return chart;
}, function() {
  $.getJSON("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/info?site=stackoverflow", function(data) {
    var totalQuestions = data.items[0].total_questions;
    var totalUnanswered = data.items[0].total_unanswered;
    var totalAnswered = totalQuestions - totalUnanswered;

    var chartData = [{
      label: "Unanswered questions on SO",
      value: totalUnanswered
    }, {
      label: "Answered questions on SO",
      value: totalAnswered
    }];

    chartElement.datum(chartData);
    chart.update();
  }).fail(function() {
    chart.noData("Something went wrong :(");
    chart.update();
  });
});
```

```css
#chart {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.2/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.2/nv.d3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="chart">
  <svg></svg>
</div>
```